# Compacting Database Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have a program that deletes any data that is older than a certain date inside my Access2010 databse, then  compacts the databse. The deleting part of the program works fine, but I am getting the error **"Invalid Argument"** when I try to compact it right after. Here is what my code looks like:

```
    'Deleting anything older than chosen before databse is compacted.
    Dim DateA As Date = Date.Now
    Dim DateB As String
    Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb"
    Dim ParentCNN = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb"
    Dim CloneCNN = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Temp.accdb"
    Dim cnn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
    Dim sql As String

    'Formatting the date to make it 7 days into the past.
    DateB = Format(DateA.AddDays(ApplicationPropertiesWindow.DeleteFilebox.SelectedIndex + 1), "MM/dd/yy")
    cnn.Open()

    'Delete everything from b_forte where proddate is less than date - chosen time.    
    sql = "DELETE * FROM b_forte WHERE ProdDate < #" & DateB & "#"

    Dim Command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()
    'Compacting the databse
    Try

        Dim JrO As New JRO.JetEngine

        cnn.Open()
        JrO.CompactDatabase(ParentCNN, CloneCNN)
        If System.IO.File.Exists("C:\Forte\Temp.accdb") Then
            System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb")
            Rename("C:\Forte\Temp.accdb", "C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb")
            Logging("Database compacted.")
            cnn.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MainTextBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Database Compression Failure :" & vbCr & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I am using vb.net 2010 and access 2010 with no password on the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to `CompactDatabase` are just the paths, and filenames, not the connection information.

**BTW** VB.NET is not case-sensitive so I wouldn't re-use JRO:

```
Dim JrO As New JRO.JetEngine
```

It will probably work as it is, but it will be confusing to read later, and it could cause a conflict at some stage.

Comment: @ChaseErnst I don't understand what you are asking. The first argument to `CompactDatabase` should be "C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb" (without the connection details). You could create a new string variable for this, and one for "C:\Forte\Temp.accdb".

Comment: I have tried that I put 

`JrO.CompactDatabase("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Fortedb.accdb", "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Temp.accdb")`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out from @Andy G that it was the connection informatoin from `CompactDatabase`. The information I had to chang ein my code was in : `CloneCNN`. The string was `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Forte\Temp.accdb"`
 and to fix the **Invalid Argument** error message I added `;Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5` to the end of `CloneCNN`.